# How to ReDraw CGRect in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, macos, drawing, core-graphics

I have the UIView Subclass:

```
ClockFace
```

Which is initialized using:

```
override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {...}
```

It is represented in my ViewController as:

```
@IBOutlet weak var analogClock: ClockFace!
```

I redraw analogClock with:

```
analogClock.drawRect(analogClock.bounds)
```

However this yields the error:

> CGContextMoveToPoint: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
>   fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `analogClock.setNeedsDisplay()`

Comment: That worked, thanks. Any ideas as to why drawRect didn't?

Comment: For views that contain custom content using UIKit or Core Graphics, the system calls the view’s drawRect: method. Your implementation of this method is responsible for drawing the view’s content into the current graphics context, which is set up by the system automatically prior to calling this method. This creates a static visual representation of your view’s content that can then be displayed on the screen. (Apple) [see here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/)

Comment: if you call setNeedsDisplay, system'll recall drawRect

Comment: So the way that the UIView is drawn is not by simply calling drawRect(_:) so one must flag the stem to do it, correct?

Comment: Thanks for your help!